# Echoing a number?

Tags: command-line, bash

For a file in sysfs, I tried using

```
echo 45>target_size
```

to set the value to 45. This failed, with an invalid entry. However, if I do:

```
x=45;echo $x>target_size
```

it works fine. Further, if I use a very big number, it gives me an error about having an invalid file number. So apparently when you echo a straight number, the terminal is interpreting that as a file descriptor, rather than a literal number. What is the proper way to  echo a number?

Comment: Welcome to AU! What do you mean by "This failed, with an invalid entry"? What makes you this didn't work?

Comment: If I write to the sysfs file, it prints a message if it receives something, saying "Attempting to set target size to ___" with whatever you put in, and then if its a valid number it eventually says "Target size now set to ___". But if I just use echo ___, it doesn't print anything. So it's apparently treating $x and the plain number as different, even though they ought to be the same thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a matter of how the shell parses your command, I think. When you do

```
echo 45>target_size
```

the shell redirects file descriptor `45` to file`target_size` and then executes `echo` with no arguments.

If instead you do

```
echo 45 >target_size
```

it redirects the standard output descriptor to file `target_size` and then executes `echo 45`.

TL;DR add whitespace before the redirection operator.

Comment: Yep, exactly right. Should be worth noting that this seems to be bash-specific. `ksh` and `dash` both echo the number into file without issues

Comment: Just checked in with the bash terminal, and this does indeed seem to be it. That's an interesting quirk that the space matters that much. Thanks!

Comment: Not so quirky: the shell is very whitespace sensitive. Whitespace is used to separate commands/keywords/arguments. You need whitespace within `[[ ]]` to separate operators/operands

Answer (score 3):

@steeldriver's answer is correct - the space between number and redirection operator matters. It seems to be an inconsistent behavior, as in my tests `echo 45>output.txt` writes 45 to file on ksh93 and dash shells.

As alternative you could always use `tee` command with `here-string` operator `<<<`.

```
tee  output_file.txt <<< "45"
```

Or with those shells that don't have `<<<` operator, `echo 45 | tee output_file.txt`

Comment: tee is not a builtin thus this solution is slower

Comment: @TomášNesrovnal slower ? Sorry, but that's a slightly bogus comment. Maybe by nano seconds, but definitelly not any slower than a shell built in. In this case speed is irrelevant, too.

Comment: Agreed. Being slower would be important only for a super-critical response time, in which case using a shell would be entirely inappropriate anyway. The days when computers were so slow that they needed maximum optimisation for everyday use are long gone, thank goodness!